# useMutation with onCompleted and refetchQueries

Tags: apollo-client

somewhere in my app I have query to fetch current user

```
  query CURRENT_USER {
    current_user {
      id
      email
      permissions { name }
    }
  }
```

Also I have authentication page where I'm using mutation:

```
  mutation login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(email: $email, password: $password) {
      token
    }
  }
```

```
  const [Login, {loading}] = useMutation(LOGIN, {
    onCompleted: (data) => sessionStorage.setItem('token', data?.login?.token),
    refetchQueries: ['CURRENT_USER'],
    awaitRefetchQueries: true,
  });

  const onSubmit = ({ email, password }) => Login({ variables: { email, password } })
```

So as you can see I want on mutation completion to store token in sessionStorage and refetch CURRENT_USER query after that. Right now it seems like `refetchQueries` fires before `onCompleted` is done.

Any way to solve that?